# Replace values for columns in dataframe by external numeric vector

Tags: r

Let's suppose I have a data frame in R with binary entries for three variables (a, b and c)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = rbinom(10, 1, 0.5), b = rbinom(10, 2, 0.3), c = rbinom(10, 4, 0.8))

df
   a b c
1  1 0 1
2  0 1 1
3  0 0 1
4  1 0 0
5  1 1 1
6  0 1 1
7  0 1 0
8  0 0 1
9  1 0 1
10 0 0 1
```

Then, I want to create an index considering the relative "presence" of each variable for all observations (rows), something like:

```
df2 <- 1/(colSums(df))

df2

  a     b     c 
0.250 0.250 0.125
```

Now, I want to return to df. For each column and for each observation if the variable has a value of 1, then replace the values by the ones in df2. Otherwise, if the original value is 0, then I want to keep it. I tried to perform a loop, but it didn't work well.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){

  df[,i][df==1] <- df2[i]

}
```

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = c(0.25, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25,  : 
>         replacement has 30 rows, data has 10

Is there an alternative way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapply` to do that, i.e.

```
mapply(function(x, y) replace(x, x==1, y), df, i1)
#where i1 <- 1/colSums(df)
```

which gives,

> ```
>              a    b c
>  [1,] 0.0000000 0.00 4
>  [2,] 0.3333333 0.25 4
>  [3,] 0.0000000 0.00 4
>  [4,] 0.3333333 0.00 3
>  [5,] 0.0000000 0.00 3
>  [6,] 0.0000000 0.00 3
>  [7,] 0.0000000 0.25 4
>  [8,] 0.3333333 0.25 3
>  [9,] 0.0000000 0.25 4
> [10,] 0.0000000 0.00 2
> ```

**Note** Your `df2` (my `i1`) values are different than mine as you did not use a `set.seed` to make the `rbinom` reproducible

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(rep(1/(colSums(df)), nrow(df)),
                         byrow = TRUE, nrow = nrow(df)))

df2[df == 0] <- 0
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df2
>       a    b     c
> 1  0.25 0.00 0.125
> 2  0.00 0.25 0.125
> 3  0.00 0.00 0.125
> 4  0.25 0.00 0.000
> 5  0.25 0.25 0.125
> 6  0.00 0.25 0.125
> 7  0.00 0.25 0.000
> 8  0.00 0.00 0.125
> 9  0.25 0.00 0.125
> 10 0.00 0.00 0.125
> ```

---

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
                     b = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                     c = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)),
                .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could find the ones first, then overwrite them by multiplication. This however only works if you want to replace ones, whereas @Sotos approach works for all.

```
df_is_1 <- df==1
df[df_is_1] <- (df_is_1*df2)[df_is_1]
```